# ic_launcher_foreground not found

Tags: android, kotlin

I was doing the Android Studio Launcher Icon tutorial and used the new background and foreground given to me in the tutorial. The problem is, when I ran it, it said it could not find the ic_launcher_foreground despite being in the file, and I'm not sure what is the problem.

I tried deleting the background and foreground, and readded it, and also even deleted the @drawable/ic_launcher_foreground but still wouldn' run the app.

Comment: Need to see your manifest, any xml-based drawables related to this icon, and a picture of your expanded `res` directories to be able to identify the issue.